# How to export data from GCP Postgres sql to a csv file in GCS through AIRFLOW?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, airflow

We are using GCP with Postgres sql. Need to export one table from postgres to a csv file in google cloud storage bucket but only through AIRFLOW. 
Not sure whether API call / Operator can be used.
Please advise if possible with sample code.

Thanks
Raj.

Comment: There's a specific operator for that [CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator, https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/gcp/sql.html#cloudsqlinstanceexportoperator]. it allows you to export from Cloud SQL to Google Storage

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do should be feasible with the [PostgresToGCSOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/postgres_to_gcs/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.postgres_to_gcs). [Here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_postgres_to_gcs.py) you can find a usage example.

Comment: Is there any documentation that shows how to pass authentication for GCS?